# How to write generic pointer on socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

How can a void* be written on a tcp socket in C++? Especially, do I need to know the type since I cannot know its data size otherwise?

In this example, I wouldn't know the data size of buf:

```
foo(const void *buf, int socket){
int n= write(socket , buf, ???);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you need to know the size of the object to be written. You do not have to know the exact type, but at least its byte size. C++ cannot smell how long the object is that is to be written.

If you know the type it should be no problem to pass the length to your function by just using the `sizeof` operator on it. But make sure to take the `sizeof` of your type, *not* the `sizeof` of a pointer to your type. I.e., if the type of your object is `YourClass`, use `sizeof(YourClass)`, not `sizeof(YourClass*)` or even `sizeof(void*)`!

Comment: But be careful, because operator sizeof on pointers does not return a true size of data, if you have for example int* and you are storing the array there, it will not return size of that array!

Comment: @DusanPlavak: Good addition, added it.

Comment: Even so, you'd better not try to write a `void*` which points to a `std::string`. The unfortunate fact is that `void*` lacks all type information, and any interesting type cannot be serialized by type-unaware code.